# running really long scripts - how to keep them running and start them again if they fail?

Tags: php, python, process, centos, process-management

I need to run a bunch of long running processes on a CENTOS server.

If I leave the processes (python/php scripts) to run sometimes the processes will stop running **because of trivial errors eg. string encoding issues** or sometimes **because the process seems to get killed by the server**.

I try to use nohup and fire the jobs from the crontab

Is there any way to keep these processes running in such a way that all the variables are saved and I can restart the script from where it stopped?

I know I can program this into the code but would prefer a generalised utility which could just keep these things running so that the script completed even if there were trivial errors.

Perhaps I need some sort of process-management tool?

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I think the best solution is to write your scripts with proper exception handling so they don't just exit without at least logging what needs to be fixed.

Comment: some profilers (eg *xdebug*) can show values of variables at the moment when error occures. so, there may be some tools that can also store it.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way to keep these processes running in such a way that all the variables are saved and i can restart the script from where it stopped?

Yes.  It's called creating a "checkpoint" or "memento".

> i know i can program this

Good.  Get started.  Each problem is unique, so you have to create, save, and reload the mementos.

> but would prefer a generalised utility which could just keep these things running so that the script completed even if there were trivial errors.

It doesn't generalize well.  Not all variables can be saved.  Only you know what's required to restart your process in  a meaningful way.

> perhaps i need some sort of process-management tool?

Not really.

> trivial errors eg. string encoding issues

Usually, we find these by unit testing.  That saves a lot of programming to work around the error.  An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of silly work-arounds.

> sometimes because the process seems to get killed by the server.

What?  You'd better find out why.  An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of silly work-arounds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem I have is that I'm running really long processes which can take up to 16-17 hours to complete and am running pretty much random HTML through complex string/xml manipulation so errors can occur pretty much at random - what's the best way to unit test for strange and wonderful encodings?

Comment: @significance:  Reduce the time to find a problem.  Rather than do all parsing on each document and wait hours to find a problem, simply read each sheet to check the encoding.  Then, after they all pass their encoding test, move on to the next step.  If you think about it, you have a sequence of many small processing steps.  If you think even further, you have a `multiprocessing` queue of processing operations on each file.

Comment: @significance: That is an entirely separate and unrelated question.  Please open a new question that addresses your **real** problem: long-running processes that take forever to find encoding issues.